# How to parse and get image path in string in flutter

Tags: flutter

This is code to upload image

```
var res;
  pickImage(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageSource);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      res = await UploadImage.uploadImage(File(pickedFile.path));
      print("image;========${pickedFile.path}");
      Logger().i(res);
      //  print("image file path:====${res}");
      setState(() {
        pickedImage = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
  }
```

i am getting response in res in below format in growable list

[image]

I want to parse image_path want to assign to string so that i can pass image in other function can any one please help me in this how we can parse and get image_path value .

Thanks

Comment: you can simply use jsonDecode(res) into a variable and later use variable["image_path"]. 

But you need to take care of statuscodes and server messages just to be sure